# No countable models

Tags: logic, model-theory

I want an example of a theory T with finite models of arbitrarily large size but T has no countably infinite model. I know that T has to be uncountable, but couldn't come up with an example.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It would be helpful if you could provide us with some background, for example: where did you encountered this problem and why?

Comment: Does $T$ need be a theory in FOL?

Answer (score 4):

In the language there is a relation symbol $\unlhd$ and a constant for every real. Let $\{q_i : i<\omega\}$ enumerate the rationals (or any other  countable dense subset of the reals). Consider the following axioms:

> $\unlhd$ is a linear order;
>
> $r\unlhd s$ for every pair of reals $r\le s$;
>
> If there are at least $n$ elements then $q_i\lhd q_j$ for all $i,j<n$ such that $q_i<q_j$.

This theory has finite models of any size. But in any infinite model all constants have to be interpreted in distinct elements. Hence it has the size of the continuum.